# 3b1b video: why does this linear combination not seem to follow the rules of REFF to derive x and y values?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-equations

Per [this video at this moment](https://youtu.be/PFDu9oVAE-g?t=629), he says we can see the solution to this equation is $\begin{bmatrix} -1\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ (yellow line). Why?

[image]

Since $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $, wouldn't it give $x+y=0$ when solving by REFF as we ignore bottom row, resulting in..

$x = 1$ & $y = 1$ when, $x+y=0$?

Comment: The reduced echelon form $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ does not mean $x = 1$ and $y = 1$.

Comment: Ok so we multiply it out, it means $x \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} + y \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = 0 \rightarrow x*1 + y*1 =0$. And... $x + y =0$ still does not give $x=-1, y=1$ as 3b1b says.. What am i getting wrong here..?

Comment: That calculations says *any* $(x, y)$ such that $x + y = 0$ is a solution; $x = -1$ and $y = 1$ is one particular solution, and more importantly *every other* solution is a scalar multiple of it.

Comment: How did he derive that, $x=-1$ and $y=1$ is one solution from a LA standpoint? Did he just plug in random numbers until it is 0?... if so wouldn't $y=-1$ & $x=1$ also work? ... This is easy to do when there's only 2d, but what if it's 3d or more. ie. $x+y+z = 0$

Comment: One way is to view one of the variables in $x + y = 0$ as a free variable (since you have more variables than you have equations), and solve for the other variable. So if $y = t$ is free, then the equation dictates that $x = -t$. Hence $(-t, t)$ is a solution for every $t \in \mathbb R$, and $t = 1$ is just one choice. The same idea works in higher dimensions, just with (potentially) more free variables.

Comment: But yes, $x = 1$ and $y = -1$ also works just fine, that's from the same method only taking $t = -1$ instead of $t = 1$; you get a solution for *every* $t$.

Comment: Amazing makes sense, so he is saying all those values of x & y will converge to 0 after the transformation $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. How about if $\lambda = 3$ instead of 2?